# Instead of repeating blocks of code, more efficient way to write this javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, rss

Here i'm just repeating the same code over and over and just incrementing the variable names. Same with the feed url call to the RSS2JSON utility.
Can I somehow write this so I don't have to repeat? I actually have 8 different feeds I'd like to use.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var cpacontent = document.getElementById('cpa');
        function showFeed(data){
            if(data.status == 'ok'){    
                var feedlength = data.items.length;
                var output = '';
                for(var i=0;i<1;++i){
                    output += '<p><a href="' +
                    data.items[i].link + '" target="_blank" >' +
                    data.items[i].title + '</a>';
                }
                cpacontent.innerHTML = output;
            }
        }

        var fscontent = document.getElementById('fs');
        function showFeed2(data){
            if(data.status == 'ok'){    
                var feedlength2 = data.items.length;
                var output2 = '';
                for(var i=0;i<1;++i){
                    output2 += '<p><a href="' +
                    data.items[i].link + '" target="_blank" >' +
                    data.items[i].title + '</a>';
                }
                fscontent.innerHTML = output2;
            }
        }
        var wealthcontent = document.getElementById('wealth');
        function showFeed3(data){
            if(data.status == 'ok'){    
                var feedlength3 = data.items.length;
                var output3 = '';
                for(var i=0;i<1;++i){
                    output3 += '<p><a href="' +
                    data.items[i].link + '" target="_blank" >' +
                    data.items[i].title + '</a>';
                }
                wealthcontent.innerHTML = output3;
            }
        }    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rss2json.com/api.json?callback=showFeed1&rss_url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeedurlplaceholder1"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rss2json.com/api.json?callback=showFeed2&rss_url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeedurlplaceholder2"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rss2json.com/api.json?callback=showFeed3&rss_url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeedurlplaceholder3"></script>
```

Comment: _Can I somehow write this so I don't have to repeat?_ Yes you can! You only need/should have 1 function showFeed()

Answer (score 0):

Add a second parameter to the function to accept the element.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<script>
function myFunction(selectorID, data) {
    var element = document.getElementById('selectorID');
    if(data.status == 'ok'){    
        var dataLength = data.items.length;
        var output = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < 1; ++i){
            output += '<p> <a href="' +
            data.items[i].link + '" target="_blank" >' +
            data.items[i].title + '</a>';
        }
        cpacontent.innerHTML = output;
    }
}

myFunction("cpa", cpaData);
myFunction("fs", fsData);
myFunction("wealth", wealthData);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm giving that a shot but noticed that in the API call, there's a callback var that changes for each... (showFeed1, showFeed2, showFeed3) so I would need this to increment as the function name, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you doing well..!!

you can use one function `showFeed()` with two parameters that are `data` and `varFlag` as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function showFeed(data, varFlag){
         if(data.status == 'ok'){    
             var feedlength = data.items.length;

             var output = '';
             for(var i=0;i<1;++i){
                 output += '<p><a href="';
                 output += data.items[i].link + '" target="_blank" >';
                 output += data.items[i].title + '</a>';
             }

             if(varFlag == 'cpa') { cpacontent.innerHTML = output; }

             if(varFlag == 'fs') { fscontent.innerHTML = output; }

             if(varFlag == 'wealth') { wealthcontent.innerHTML = output; }
         }
     }

     var cpacontent = document.getElementById('cpa');
     showFeed(data, 'cpa');

     var fscontent = document.getElementById('fs');
     showFeed(data, 'fs');

     var wealthcontent = document.getElementById('wealth');     
     showFeed(data, 'wealth');    
</script>
```